# Where can I get a VB6 IDE

Tags: visual-studio, ide, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile legacy VB6 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229868/how-to-compile-legacy-vb6-code)

Where can I find an IDE for VB6? I'm guessing I need to get a copy of Visual Studio 6, but I've been googling for hours and I can't find anything.

I need to do some simple maintenance on an old VB6 application. Upgrading it to .NET would cause lots of work on the deployment and testing side of things so I would prefer to avoid that. And I would rather not resort to notepad and command line compiler either.

Is there any better solution to my problem?

Comment: If you don't have a license for VB6, then you're out of legal options. Microsoft no longer supports the VB6 IDE. If you have to perform maintenance on that code, then your company should start thinking about spending the money to make the code maintainable - in other words, to rewrite it.

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted to hear but it answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708/. Also, note that an MSDN license should include a license for VB6

Comment: Visual Studio 6 is no longer available, part of the settlement between Microsoft and Sun.  The VB6 IDE is exempt from this settlement, it doesn't have any dependency on Java.  You can get it through an MSDN subscription.  Not sure what level is required, I know Universal has it.  You'll have to check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Legal options:

1. There are many copies of visual studio 6.0 on eBay that look legit.
2. Find someone that has VB6 and have them fix it.
3. Get an MSDN subscription (unsure which level is needed - Hans says Universal includes VB6)

Comment: +1. There is also 3, get an MSDN subscription (unsure which level is needed)

Comment: You are correct. That is actually how I have my copy :P

Comment: You are right, ebay has a lot of those on sale for ~300$. I think you just found me a way out of this.

Answer (score 1):

If converting to VB.NET is an option, you could check out Microsofts upgrade assement tool at:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9639.

I can't believe VB6 is still alive, not too long ago I had to write an ActiveX control for use with VB6.

Comment: Check out the Microsoft upgrade tool and you will quickly realize why VB6 is still in use :(

Comment: COBOL is still alive too.