# Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 upgrade assessment Tool Error

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

This is the first time I am using upgrade assessment tool and it gives me the following error when the analysis is performed:

> Problems occurred during analysis. Please check the following error message(s):
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Do you want to exit?

Here is my code that I developed in VB 6.0

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim line As String

Dim name As String
name = Text1.Text

If Text1.Text = Null Or Text1.Text = "" Then
MsgBox ("Please enter your name")
Else
    MsgBox ("Welcome, " + Text1.Text)
    If Option1.Value = True Then
    line = "Admin"
    MsgBox (name + ", you have selected the following items " + line)

    ElseIf Option2.Value = True Then
    line = "User"
    MsgBox (name + ", you have selected the following items " + line)

    Else
    MsgBox ("You have not selected any options! Please select one of the options given in the right panel")
    End If
'
End If

End Sub
```

I also tried a simple hello world application but it still gives me the same error. 
Note: I do not have Visual Studio on my computer. 
I am using Windows XP. Vb 6.0. .Net framework 1.1

Comment: You may need to install the VB6 IDE in order to use that upgrade assessment thingy. I can't remember offhand and I don't have it installed on this Android phone :)

Comment: VB6 IDE. I am not sure where to download that from. I downloaded a software from a CD. From my understanding, it has everything needed to run the tool.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft requirements state that VB6 is required. This might only mean the runtime, but ...
[Visual Basic 6.0 to Visual Basic .NET Upgrade Assessment Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9639)

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Ish Click the link and compare the listed requirements with your setup. There is a Visual Basic runtime install available that installs the files (Dlls) needed to run Visual Basic applications, however I believe you will need Visual Basic 6 installed, not just the run time. I posted the link so you can see the other requirements.

Comment: +1 Beaner is saying that you need the VB6 IDE installed. The VB6 compiler and editor. Which you must have used to develop the code in VB6 in the first place (it says in your question you developed this VB6 code). Or alternatively [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029361/15639) are some places where you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the requirement of VB6, this tool has a dependency with msvcp71.dll, which is a module belonging to the Microsoft C Runtime Library.

Ensure you have that module or get it somewhere in the internet (I've just downloaded from dll-files.com), then copy to c:\windows\system32.

You will also need to install Excel 2003, which is used by the tool to generate the reports.