# VB6 code reader

Tags: vb6, ide, vb6-migration

I have some VB6 files which I want to read and explore (to ultimately convert into .NET). I do not need to execute or write code.

I am looking for a piece of software that will help me read and explore these files. Notepad++ would be fine if I could get the "Find in All Open Files" to work.

Can anyone suggest an application I can use to make reading and exploring these files easier?

I do not have a copy of Visual Studio 6.

Thanks

Comment: but do you have a newer version of Visual Studio? The later ones include a converter from VB6 which does a reasonable job.

Comment: Yes I have visual studio 2010. Will take a look at this now, thanks.

Comment: If you have an MSDN subscription, you may be able to download VB6 with no additional charge. Or buy on ebay. See [this question for more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029361/15639)

Comment: @Bathsheba The VB6 converter has been removed from the most recent versions of Visual Studio. I can't remember right now whether it's in VS2010.

Comment: @MarkJ It's in VS2008; not sure about the express version though.

Comment: There is a plugin for modern Visual Studio for VB6: http://vbvs.vbdevelopment.de/ . "Visual Basic® Tools for Visual Studio is an extension for Visual Studio® allowing to work on classic Visual Basic® projects within Visual Studio®. It´s intention is to provide better development tools for teams which have to maintain legacy code written in VB6..."

Comment: Someone wrote a language definition for Notepad++ which may also work nicely: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?838637-Suggestions-for-VB6-Syntax-Code-Plug-In-for-Notepad

Comment: OR you can just add bas cls frm to the extensions list for the Visual Basic language already in NP++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get "Find in All Open Files" working in Notepad++, which has a formatting mode for VB6.