# Is there anywhere I can download VB6 these days?

Tags: vb6

I have a couple of decades of experience with VB6. I could share this knowledge with those people who are still asking questions about it: but I cannot test my code or confirm my thinking without a copy of the thing. I know it's very, very obsolete: but I lost my job last year due to disability, so I am coding at home.

I have the latest c#, obviously, in the form of the Express edition of the latest Visual Studio. But is VB6 available from any ***legitimate*** sources?

Comment: There was a version of VB5 called the "Control Creation Edition" that was free if you can locate a copy. You could not compile EXEs with it, just ActiveX stuff, but the IDE was the same and for messing around/running code snippets in the debugger it works as expected.

Comment: thanks! I shall bear that in mind if I cannot find VB6.

Comment: See the answers to the equivalent question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029122/where-can-i-get-a-vb6-ide

Comment: @Hamish, did you manage to get a copy in the end?

Comment: I did not. VB5CCE doesn't seem to be available for download now. The best answer I got was that if you subscribe to MSDN, you can download it. Since I am not working, that's too expensive for me: but it would work for anyone else.

Comment: I did not chase up local schools and colleges, as you suggested. Honestly forgot by the time I could have gotten around to it. I might give it a go. But I have less energy to spend at the moment, so answering Q on here took a back seat, alas.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 is available to MSDN subscribers

Comment: Thanks! Alas, without work, I also lack the income to get such a thing (food is kind of the priority). One to look at if/when I get an income again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can still buy original sealed copies on ebay.  But the prices are still surprisingly high, probably due to the rarity and lack of MS support.

Have you considered switching to VBA instead?  Modern MS Office versions have this installed as standard (I think) and according to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications): "Microsoft has clearly stated that they have no plans to remove VBA from the Windows version of Office."

VBA is pretty close to VB6 apart from being able to compile it.  But for syntax and general programming help I think it's still valid for testing out code samples and so forth.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it specifically to help out on this forum. So I'd like intellisense etc. My knowledge of it got pretty good (I still remember the odd compiler bug) and I'd like to help others, if I can. So having the ADODB objects etc available for referencing etc would be a great boon.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could try is to approach any schools, colleges or small businesses in your area.  All three of these kinds of establishments are likely to have reasons to own legitimate copies of VB6 an have probably long since stopped using them but they may still be sat on a shelf gathering dust.

Schools and colleges love to sell off old assets because it keeps the accountants happy and frees up some forgotten cash to buy books and chalk with :).  Perhaps you could offer to buy them at a low price.  I'm sure they'll consider it.

Comment: An excellent idea - thanks!