# Move VB6 compiler to new PC

Tags: vb6

I've been asked to help out with some work on an old VB6 application for a client. They have one PC with VB6 installed, but it is an old machine running Windows XP. They would like to transfer it to a new computer, but they've lost the original Visual Studio disks.

Would it possible to just copy over the necessary files to at least get the compiler and linker working? I realise it might be a bit more involved to get the full IDE operational, but if anyone could give us a head-start on whether this might be possible it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered creating a virtual machine from your XP machine? I don't think you will be able to create a running compiler from an existing installation.

Comment: No that's not possible. You could try the virtual machine route suggested by Filburt. Otherwise you need to get the install disks for VB6 (or Visual Studio 6 which contained VB6). If you or the client have an MSDN subscription you can download it (may depend on the level of MSDN subscription you have). Alternatively you can buy the install disks on eBay or similar. Disclaimer: this advice was adapted from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029361/15639). Good luck with the project!

Comment: A few years ago it was possible to download the orginal iso´s from Microsoft with a developer MSDN - but don´t remember what MSDN and also don´t know if this is still possible.

Comment: If you read the EULA you'll find this product was licensed to a *developer* and not a company.  The original developer has "transfer rights" but companies who just pass this software around are most likely violating the license terms.  If you're a VB6 developer you can install your own copy and use it, you just can't leave it behind for others to use.  So if this company wants that they need to keep a developer on staff and go through an MSDN Library Subscription for him to get it.

Comment: The vcirtual machine idea sounds like a good approach, but I have no experience in setting anything like this up. Could anyone point to a good introductory article, or step by step guide on how to do this?

Comment: The company does have a MSDN subscription, through the MAPS. programme, but the level isn't high enough to download old tools, only the latest visual studio. They did have someone offer to download it for them, but they said it would not work anyway, as the license is different for download vs CD. Version. Is that correct?