# Visual Basic 6 and Visual Basic in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

Is the code used in Visual Studio for Visual Basic the same as the code for Visual Basic 6.0?

The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE is no longer supported, so I can't get a hold of that version, but a tutoring pupil of mine is doing work in Studio Basic 6. Will I be able to help using Visual Studio or are they different coding languages?

Comment: There have been many generations of Basic, often quite incompatible with each other.  VB6 was the last version of the previous generation, started in 1990 and ended in 1998.  VB.NET was a very drastic redesign with significant syntax differences, the odds that you can be helpful are quite low.  Do question the pupil about the tooling choice, educating a new programmer with such outdated tooling is not very productive and does not do him any favors.

Comment: Although VB6 IDE "is not longer supported", its easy possible to get an installer working on actual windows versions. For two old applications I need to have a VB6 installed - it works fine on Windows 10/64bit

Comment: It is true that the VB6 IDE is no longer supported. But it is [still possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029361/15639) to obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Visual Basic is Visual Basic 15.

Visual Basic 6.0 is not supported in Visual Studio:

> Visual Studio 2010 does not provide tools for upgrading applications and projects from Visual Basic 6.0. If you want to upgrade your project from Visual Basic 6.0 to Visual Basic 2010, you can use the upgrade tools provided with earlier versions of Visual Studio and then upgrade the project again in Visual Studio 2010.

Source: *[How to: Upgrade a Project from Visual Basic 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bszew91f(v=vs.100))*

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. The issue is that we would need to be transferring VB14 code into VB6 rather than the other way around. I'm not sure why schools still use VB6 since it is no longer supported.

Comment: That won't work and you'll likely run into a lot of constructs that are possible in VB.NET that are just not possible in VB6,

Comment: I agree with @jessehouwing, just let them know this is not possible

Comment: AFAIK the current Visual Studio Express edition is freely ("as in beer") available.

Comment: @DaveInCaz I've been looking for a link, without luck

Answer (score 0):

You can install visual studio 6, and can use visual basic 6,
I have installed in windows 10.
There is some problem during installing. I have removed mdac_typ.exe, and continued installing.

Answer (score -4):

Visual Basic 6.0 is an old version of Visual Studio 2010.

The programming concept is the same, but the syntax is different, so if you learn on Visual Basic 6.0 you will understand the programming concept, but you only should know how to write the syntax of Visual Studio 2010, and it won't take much time, because there are a lot of things that are the same, and there some differences in function names and how to call it, but it isn't complex to know these differences. But in Visual Studio 2010 there some new functions and tools that help you more in creating the applications.

Comment: Visual Studio isn't a programming language.

Comment: Guessing he meant VB6 vs. VB.Net but worded it poorly.